# How can I pass prove (Test::More) an argument, e.g. an API URL?

Tags: perl, testing, test-more, perl-prove

Parts of my test suite relies on an API URL. Sometimes I want to run my test using another URL. Is there a way to pass this argument to `prove`, or would I need to edit the file that defined the API URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe set a default URL in the test program but allow it to be overridden by an environment variable.

```
my $url = $ENV{MY_TEST_URL} // 'http://api.example.com/';
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `prove` (`perldoc prove`) contains the following:

> Arguments to Tests
> It is possible to supply arguments to tests. To do so separate them from
> prove's own arguments with the arisdottle, '`::`'. For example
>
> ```
>  prove -v t/mytest.t :: --url http://example.com
> ```
>
> would run `t/mytest.t` with the options '`--url http://example.com`'. When
> running multiple tests they will each receive the same arguments.

Thus, the parts after the `::` will appear in `@ARGV` for the test script. I prefer offering a combination of options for passing args. For example:

```
my $url = $ARGV[0] // $ENV{'TEST_URL'};
```